# Oracle DB sqlplus issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Oracle Server DB 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 installed on my local pc.

When i try to run the command `select * from idc_geraet` with sqldeveloper i get the expected result, but if i run the same command with sqlplus i get an error saying that no rows are selected. I'm logged in at both with the same schema (scott).

When i run the command `select * from idc_person` i get the expected result with both programms - sqlplus and sqldeveloper.
How is that possible?

thanks for your help,
Armin

Comment: Maybe you are connected to same schema but from another instance. Another option is that you are missing COMMIT from sqldeveloper.

Comment: @Osy there is no commit missing and i've got only on instance called orcl

Comment: @Osy you were right. i forgot the commit. thank you ;)

Comment: Good! Let´s formalize our agreement ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible options:

- You are connected to same schema but from another instance.
- Missing COMMIT from sqldeveloper.